# Android 2.1 standard recycle bin icon

Tags: android, icons, android-sdk-2.1

I'd like to use in my own app the standard android icon, which is displayed when I delete widgets from my desktop (Android 2.1). But I can't find it in the SDK.

Where do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to use in my own app the standart android icon, which is displayed when I delete widgets from my desktop (Android 2.1)

There is no such icon in the OS, because the launcher is not part of the OS. Home screens are applications.

> But I can't find it in the sdk.

That is because it is not part of the OS.

> Where do I find it?

You find it in [the Launcher2 project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher_trashcan_normal_holo.png) in the AOSP.